# How to Call Functions one by one in swift?

Tags: swift

I have two Functions

Calling these Two Functions as follows

```
fun c(){

  a()

  b()
}
```

Problem am facing here is Before getting the Response of **a** method **b** also executing

but I want to execute one after another

Please suggest

Comment: Did you try completion blocks ?

Comment: you will **not** execute `b` before `a` has returned, what *may* happen is that `a` does some async work in a different thread. If that is the case you need to provide a callback to `a` which it has to call after it finished whatever asnyc task it is doing

Comment: Your example code is incomplete, It is not clear whether function `a` and `b` are synchronous or asynchronous. Provide more relevant example.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchsemaphore

Answer (score 1):

**Option1** : call `bbb` from inside completion of `aaa`

```
func aaa() {
   Api.taskl {
       bbb()
   }
}
```

**Option2:** async both inside a custom serial queue like this

```
let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "queuename")
serialQueue.sync { 
 aaa()
}
serialQueue.sync { 
 bbb()
}
```

Comment: If `aaa` dispatches asynchronous work a serial dispatch queue won't help.

Comment: @Paulw11 sure it should be in same queue , btw it's a background queue so no need to insert another one inside it

Comment: Ok, if `aaa` dispatches its asynchronous task on `serialQueue` then it will work, but you haven't specified this nor have you provided `serialQueue` to `aaa`.  Assuming that the OP's problem is that `a` dispatches serial work on some arbitrary queue asynchronously (which they haven't actually stated, but it seems likely from the situation they are describing) then your code as shown in option 2 won't help.

Comment: in this case he may use option 1 , btw he should give feedback

Answer (score 0):

You can use closure:

method a() would be:

```
func a(_ completion: (() -> ())?){

//Do all of your staff, at the end call this:
 completion()
}
```

You can call a method in two ways:

```
a() //this will not execute the callback

//this is a callback where you call the other function
a(){ 
   b()
}
```